# How to create pipeline in spark which performs different transformations on different RDD's

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 topics in the kafka stream, I wanted to perform one transformation on some set of RDD's and another on rest of the RDD's.

Below is the code to get the kafka data in spark stream

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> notifications = 
        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class, kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.class, kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicSet);
```

This notification contains 2 different topics, lets say X and Y,
I wanted to perform addition operation on topic X and subtraction operation on topic Y

is anything like below is available.
it is just a model of what I need and if the same thing is achieved in any other way with spark. please let me know

```
notification.if( topicName is X).map(valuex -> valuex+1).else( topicName is Y).map(valuey -> valuey-1).collect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating two streams, like notifications1 for topic X and notifications2 for topic Y and perform the map operation on them seperately.

After completion of map operation, you can join the streams using join operation.

Refer below link for more info on joining streams.
[Joining two streams](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/07%20Spark%20Streaming/13%20Joining%20DStreams.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Will try 2 streams

Comment: I used Single stream, but filtered for each topic and get the DStream and joined at the end.